# scanner with tokenizer only give one word of a line?

Tags: java

I have used Scanner to read an input string from the user:

`Scanner s =new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Insert Command: ");
         input=s.next();`

Then I used StringTokenizer to split the input into words, but the token only take the first word:

```
StringTokenizer command=new StringTokenizer(input);

         System.out.println( command.countTokens());
         System.out.println( command.nexttoken())
         System.out.println( command.nexttoken());
```

for example: the input is: "find A www.google.com"
The output I got was:

`1
find
Exception occured`

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well ... first of all, you are using StringTokenizer, which has been deprecated for several versions of Java. You should use String's split method or regex, instead.

The `next()` method only takes the first token, not the entire line, so try with other methods of Scanner. Try your code again, with `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.

The `next()` method stops reading at the first space.